# ClassCastException in query by List<Class>

Tags: jsp, google-app-engine, exception, google-cloud-datastore

**Google App Engine** by page.jsp

```
<%
    Query query = pm.newQuery(Store.class);
    query.setFilter("id=='" + store + "'");
    query.setOrdering("name asc");
    List<Store> aList = (List<Store>) query.execute();
    System.out.println("aList==isEmpty?"+aList.isEmpty());
%>
```

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Blob cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Note: wanted to mark this question as possible duplicate of [GAE ClassCastException Long cannot be cast to double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26257341/gae-classcastexception-long-cannot-be-cast-to-double) but couldn't (because StackOverflow said the other question has no accepted answer or answer with positive score).</sup>

---

The exception means you have at least one `Store` entity saved in the Datastore where you saved it with a property type `Blob` but in your Java entity you specified it as `String` and when you want to query it and convert it back to the Java class, the attempted conversion `Blob` -> `String` throws exception.

What you may do is read all `Store` entitites using the low-level Datastore api, and change the `Blob` properties to `String` which are supposed to be `String` in the first place, then resave those entities (or change the type of your Java field from `String` to `Blob` if it is supposed to be `Blob`). Or if the current entities are not important (e.g. test data), just delete them.

Documentation: [Java low-level Datastore API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/)

Comment: If you only have one or few entities with this problem, you can also find the offending property in the Datastore viewer, and manually reset it to null first, then to String.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry!!
I was fixed this issue.
Answer:

**Modify**

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
```

**To**

```
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
```