# GAE ClassCastException Long cannot be cast to double

Tags: java

Getting exception when trying to fetch data from datastore entity.
here is my code:

```
PersistenceManager pmf = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

try {
    Query query = pmf.newQuery(DocHeader.class);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<DocHeader> docHeaders = (List<DocHeader>) query.execute();
```

Anyone can help in this issue.

here is my object

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class DocHeader {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.SEQUENCE)
    private Long docHeaderId;

    @Persistent
    private Double previousPayment;

    @Persistent
    private Double currentBalance;

    @Persistent
    private Double totalAccountBalance;

    @Persistent
    private String accountRepresentative;

    @Persistent
    private Double minPayment;

}
```

Comment: Is `DocHeader` your own class?

Comment: yes this is my own class.and i store data using this class.when fetching data is shows error

Comment: Can you post the source of this class (edit the question)?

Comment: errm, and the most important fact of all? the ClassCastException itself ... and its stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception

> ClassCastException Long cannot be cast to double

means you have at least one `DocHeader` entity saved in the Datastore where you saved it for one of its property being a `Long` number but in your Java entity you specified it as `Double` and when you want to query it and convert it back to the Java class, the attempted conversion `Long` -> `Double` throws exception.

What you may do is read all `DocHeader` entitites using the low-level Datastore api, and change the `Long` properties to `Double` which are supposed to be `Double` in the first place, then resave those entities. Or if the current entities are not important (e.g. test data), just delete them.

Documentation: [Java low-level Datastore API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/)